# Copyright infringement on an image from an article of mine

Tags: copyright, legal, infringement, dmca

I just received a notification from my hosting provider which told me that a certain company sent a Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA") copyright infringement notice regarding an image found in an article from my site. The image is a print ad and it was meant to offer them exposure. The article itself is a collection of print ads. The hosting provider removed the image from the server and I removed the link from the article. Do I have to worry about other legal issues if the image has been removed?

Comment: When it comes to ads, logos, trademarks and stuff like that, it's always a good idea to *ask* before you "offer them exposure" on a website, in an article, in a game or other such places.

Comment: But asking everyone included in an article doesn't transform into spam?

Answer (score 2):

**Legal issues are actions of people.** If someone wants to sue you for an image you *had* on your site, they can. Most likely though, they went for the DMCA notice because that is what they wanted. Should they have been after more, you would have received a legal letter already.

Should you have other such images in your site, remove them ASAP and stop doing this. There is no excuse for using someone else's work if it does not fall into *fair use* and, even if it does, people object all the time because [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) is not an absolute set of rules.

If someone is unhappy about your use of their material and you are not trying to raise a awareness for a cause, it is best to be a good netizen and comply. One day, you may be on the other end of this.